# iPhone Android : Memory Handling  , which one uses more memory ?

Tags: android, iphone, memory

In iPhone sdk:

```
NSString * abc= @"123"; 
NSString *temp=abc;
```

In Android:

```
String abc ="123";   
String temp=abc;
```

In this case, which one uses more memory?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to tell - these are two different languages, running on completely different operating systems & hardware. Objective-C is compiled to native code, whereas Android's Java is compiled into bytecode, and then interpreted at runtime.

However, because Strings are a built-in construct to both languages, it's extremely likely that the implementation is very efficient on both. Basically you don't have to worry about the memory efficiency of handling Strings in mobile apps - there are far more pressing concerns!

Comment: thx for your comments. i am worrying about the memory leaking in android. I was developing iphone application before, now i have to do android development. Do you have some suggestion about handling memory leaking in android?

Comment: Memory leaks in Android are most often related to Contexts - see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html and also http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=696